# Creating multiple Windows 7/8 system recovery drives on one external USB drive?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, windows-8, usb

When I'm creating a system recovery drive, it always warns me that "everything on the drive will be deleted".

I need to create recovery drives for 30 computers, and I have a 1 TB USB external hard drive - it would be perfect if I could keep all the "recovery disks on one device, instead of buying and maintaining 30 separate Pendrives / Blu Rays

Does anyone have any idea how to do it?

(I don't mean keeping multiple system images which I know is possible - I mean keeping multiple system recovery drives so that the installation is clean with the original factory settings).

Thanks for any help!

/PS I checked the forum and other threads do not address this subject/

Answer (score 0):

For linux try this: [Multiboot](http://sourceforge.net/projects/multibootusb/)

For windows, I can't see any tool which clearly supports 7/8/10

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it will work with all mobos but have you tried partitioning the hard drive itself? The bootloader should then list separate partitions as separate boot points.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason i can think of as to why you are prompted that the entire disk will be formatted is because, essentially, you are telling Windows that that sole USB disk is going to be your system backup and that it will not be used for anything else; additionally, I would probably also guess that it would like to make sure you want to use the entire disk space to ensure your backups are complete.

I, for one, wouldn't be using a system backup disk as a day-to-day USB storage - regardless of if I partitioned it or not - there will always be a potential to format an incorrect partition or accidentally delete a file/folder on the wrong partition.

**If you want to take multiple snapshots of Windows system configurations then, of course, you can always use DISM to capture a volume as a WIM. You can always redploy this back down to restore an OS.**